# Regarding API fetching locally it is throwing 404 error to me

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, axios, frontend

I have been trying to fetch the data locally with the help of Axios API.

But I don't know what is going on wrong with the code. It is throwing a 404 error for me.

I will appreciate any help.
I have provided the code below here.

```
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function GridExample() {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("src/variables/carddataa.js");
        setMyData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(error.message);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (isError) {
    return <div>Error: {isError}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Row xs={2} md={3} className="g-3">
        {myData.map((post) => {
          const { id, card_title, card_subtitle, card_text } = post;
          return (
            <Col key={id}>
              <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{card_title}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Subtitle>{card_subtitle}</Card.Subtitle>
                  <Card.Text>{card_text}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GridExample;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to fetch data from a local file using Axios. However, the URL you're passing to axios.get() appears to be incorrect, which is why you're getting a 404 error.

If you're trying to fetch data from a local file, you should use the file:// protocol in the URL. Also, make sure to include the correct path to the file.

For example, if your carddataa.js file is located in the src/variables directory of your project, you can modify your axios.get() call like this:

```js
const response = await axios.get("file:///path/to/your/project/src/variables/carddataa.js");
```

Replace /path/to/your/project with the actual path to your project directory.

Also, make sure that the carddataa.js file actually exists in the specified location and that it's accessible by your application.

Comment: What you are referring file? What should I do on this actual path C://Users/HP/Desktop/Alumni Connect/Black Dashboard/alumni_connect_frontend/src/variables/dataa.json